# sonarqube background task failed

Tags: java, maven, exception, sonarqube

I have a problem with sonarqube.
sometimes but not always the background task failed with the following error:

```
org.sonar.ce.task.projectanalysis.component.VisitException: Visit of Component {key=XXXXXXXX,type=DIRECTORY} failed
        at org.sonar.ce.task.projectanalysis.component.VisitException.rethrowOrWrap(VisitException.java:44)
        at org.sonar.ce.task.projectanalysis.component.VisitorsCrawler.visit(VisitorsCrawler.java:74)
        at org.sonar.ce.task.projectanalysis.component.VisitorsCrawler.visitChildren(VisitorsCrawler.java:110)
        at org.sonar.ce.task.projectanalysis.component.VisitorsCrawler.visitImpl(VisitorsCrawler.java:97)
        at org.sonar.ce.task.projectanalysis.component.VisitorsCrawler.visit(VisitorsCrawler.java:72)
        at org.sonar.ce.task.projectanalysis.component.VisitorsCrawler.visitChildren(VisitorsCrawler.java:110)
        at org.sonar.ce.task.projectanalysis.component.VisitorsCrawler.visitImpl(VisitorsCrawler.java:97)
        at org.sonar.ce.task.projectanalysis.component.VisitorsCrawler.visit(VisitorsCrawler.java:72)
        at org.sonar.ce.task.projectanalysis.component.VisitorsCrawler.visitChildren(VisitorsCrawler.java:110)
        at org.sonar.ce.task.projectanalysis.component.VisitorsCrawler.visitImpl(VisitorsCrawler.java:97)
        at org.sonar.ce.task.projectanalysis.component.VisitorsCrawler.visit(VisitorsCrawler.java:72)
        at org.sonar.ce.task.projectanalysis.component.VisitorsCrawler.visitChildren(VisitorsCrawler.java:110)
        at org.sonar.ce.task.projectanalysis.component.VisitorsCrawler.visitImpl(VisitorsCrawler.java:97)
        at org.sonar.ce.task.projectanalysis.component.VisitorsCrawler.visit(VisitorsCrawler.java:72)
        at org.sonar.ce.task.projectanalysis.component.VisitorsCrawler.visitChildren(VisitorsCrawler.java:110)
        at org.sonar.ce.task.projectanalysis.component.VisitorsCrawler.visitImpl(VisitorsCrawler.java:97)
        at org.sonar.ce.task.projectanalysis.component.VisitorsCrawler.visit(VisitorsCrawler.java:72)
        at org.sonar.ce.task.projectanalysis.component.VisitorsCrawler.visitChildren(VisitorsCrawler.java:110)
        at org.sonar.ce.task.projectanalysis.component.VisitorsCrawler.visitImpl(VisitorsCrawler.java:97)
        at org.sonar.ce.task.projectanalysis.component.VisitorsCrawler.visit(VisitorsCrawler.java:72)
        at org.sonar.ce.task.projectanalysis.component.VisitorsCrawler.visitChildren(VisitorsCrawler.java:110)
        at org.sonar.ce.task.projectanalysis.component.VisitorsCrawler.visitImpl(VisitorsCrawler.java:97)
        at org.sonar.ce.task.projectanalysis.component.VisitorsCrawler.visit(VisitorsCrawler.java:72)
        at org.sonar.ce.task.projectanalysis.component.VisitorsCrawler.visitChildren(VisitorsCrawler.java:110)
        at org.sonar.ce.task.projectanalysis.component.VisitorsCrawler.visitImpl(VisitorsCrawler.java:97)
        at org.sonar.ce.task.projectanalysis.component.VisitorsCrawler.visit(VisitorsCrawler.java:72)
        at org.sonar.ce.task.projectanalysis.step.ExecuteVisitorsStep.execute(ExecuteVisitorsStep.java:51)
        at org.sonar.ce.task.step.ComputationStepExecutor.executeStep(ComputationStepExecutor.java:81)
        at org.sonar.ce.task.step.ComputationStepExecutor.executeSteps(ComputationStepExecutor.java:72)
        at org.sonar.ce.task.step.ComputationStepExecutor.execute(ComputationStepExecutor.java:59)
        at org.sonar.ce.task.projectanalysis.taskprocessor.ReportTaskProcessor.process(ReportTaskProcessor.java:81)
        at org.sonar.ce.taskprocessor.CeWorkerImpl$ExecuteTask.executeTask(CeWorkerImpl.java:209)
        at org.sonar.ce.taskprocessor.CeWorkerImpl$ExecuteTask.run(CeWorkerImpl.java:191)
        at org.sonar.ce.taskprocessor.CeWorkerImpl.findAndProcessTask(CeWorkerImpl.java:158)
        at org.sonar.ce.taskprocessor.CeWorkerImpl$TrackRunningState.get(CeWorkerImpl.java:133)
        at org.sonar.ce.taskprocessor.CeWorkerImpl.call(CeWorkerImpl.java:85)
        at org.sonar.ce.taskprocessor.CeWorkerImpl.call(CeWorkerImpl.java:53)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:304)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Metric with key 'SMELL_DEBT' does not exist
        at org.sonar.ce.task.projectanalysis.metric.MetricRepositoryImpl.getByKey(MetricRepositoryImpl.java:73)
        at org.sonar.ce.task.projectanalysis.api.measurecomputer.MeasureComputerContextImpl.getChildrenMeasures(MeasureComputerContextImpl.java:124)
        at com.qualinsight.plugins.sonarqube.smell.plugin.extension.AbstractSmellMeasureComputer.aggregator(AbstractSmellMeasureComputer.java:112)
        at com.qualinsight.plugins.sonarqube.smell.plugin.extension.AbstractSmellMeasureComputer.compute(AbstractSmellMeasureComputer.java:97)
        at com.qualinsight.plugins.sonarqube.smell.plugin.extension.AbstractSmellMeasureComputer.compute(AbstractSmellMeasureComputer.java:90)
        at com.qualinsight.plugins.sonarqube.smell.plugin.extension.SmellDebtComputer.compute(SmellDebtComputer.java:31)
        at org.sonar.ce.task.projectanalysis.measure.MeasureComputersVisitor.visitAny(MeasureComputersVisitor.java:65)
        at org.sonar.ce.task.projectanalysis.component.TypeAwareVisitorWrapper.visitAny(TypeAwareVisitorWrapper.java:77)
        at org.sonar.ce.task.projectanalysis.component.VisitorsCrawler.visitNode(VisitorsCrawler.java:117)
        at org.sonar.ce.task.projectanalysis.component.VisitorsCrawler.visitImpl(VisitorsCrawler.java:100)
        at org.sonar.ce.task.projectanalysis.component.VisitorsCrawler.visit(VisitorsCrawler.java:72)
        ... 42 more
```

Have you ever encountered this problem and how did you fix it
thank you in advance for your help